# Azure Search - Searching in Specific Folder

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I just wanna search into a specific folder in my Azure Blob Container.

I'm using Azure Search Service.

For example, I have the following structure:
[image]

I desire to search all files regards to Client 01 who are into the "Cli01" folder.

Thanks

Comment: For future reference, I recommend making the question less ambiguous/more detailed, because you really have 2 questions/issues to deal with (which I think we have fleshed out in the answer comments).

Answer (score -1):

You can do what you want via the `query` parameter when you create the data source.

```
{
"name" : "blob-datasource",
"type" : "azureblob",
"credentials" : { "connectionString" : "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<account name>;AccountKey=<account key>;" },
"container" : { "name" : "my-container", "query" : "<optional-virtual-directory-name>" }
}
```

Here is the relevant documentation you want to look at for this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-indexing-azure-blob-storage

Comment: It is possible to create a main Index, and one DataSource and Indexer for each client in my system?

Comment: You could have 1 index. Your index could contain a field called "clientId", and your blobs need to have a metadata that indicates what the clientId for that document needs to be.

But you still need individual datasource and indexer, which will pick up data from a specific directory and write to that one target index. The indexer will figure out the clientId by looking at the metadata that you added earlier.

Comment: Having given this some thought, you could simply achieve your scenario without multiple indexers/datasources.

You have 1 index with a field called clientId. And then make sure any blob you add (doesn't matter which directory) has a metadata field that says what clientId that document belongs to. Then you can simply have 1 datasource encompassing the entire container and 1 indexer that uses that datasource.

The indexer will need to use the metadata field via field mappings to populate the clientId field.

Comment: Hi, Arvind. Firstly, Thank you. 
But the question is, how can I add this field to my Index once all my content is dynamically uploaded to a container? I saw a lot of examples about how to add fields to index, but these are using CosmoDB or SQL. It is not my case, I'm using Blob Storage.

Comment: Hi, Arvind. In this, case I can use field metadata called "metadata_storage_path" to filter because it already has my "clientId". How can I filter this metadata_storage_path and the same time as I search my "content" by a term.

Comment: Daniel, here is an idea. Azure search has a extractTokenAtPosition field mapping function. What you can do is - your index has a client id field. You can use the field mapping function I specified, split on the "/" token and use the metadata_storage_path (as you rightly indicated). Then you can specify the position parameter to find the token that corresponds to the clientId.

Here is documentation about that field mapping function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-indexer-field-mappings#extracttokenatposition

Comment: If you do that, then you can issue a search query like
POST /indexes/<indexName>/docs/search?api-version=<apiVersion>  
{  
  "search": "content:<some content> AND clientId:<some id>",  
  "queryType": "full",  
  "searchMode": "all"  
}

To search on both the content and the clientId.
You can optionally choose to search on the content and then filter on the clientId. I recommend looking at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-query-overview and following any links from there

Comment: Do you mind if later on I answer my own question and explain a little bit my scenario to help others in the same situation? And then mark my question as answered. Anyway, thank you Arvind

Comment: Sure. Go for it.